# Jupyter Notebook Copy mechanism

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I am trying to make a copy of a readonly jupyter notebook (made by setting the chattr `i` bit with a `644` permission). The notebook copy fails when the kernel is set to Python2 or Python3. It only opens a blank page. Interestingly a similar notebook with a R kernel successfully makes the copy.

*Does jupyter kernels have special calls for this `make a copy` UI?*

As far as I can tell `make a copy` triggers [notebook.js](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/606b7377ae53dafebaee77f184194b8466544c0b/notebook/static/notebook/js/notebook.js#L2778) which is handled by [handler.py](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/179bb24fbf79d153812858126127a91431da3319/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py#L147). I put a listener in `handler.py` to debug this but it seems like the make a copy is not even entering the context. I tried putting in a alert box in the `notebook.js` as well before [line 2781](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/606b7377ae53dafebaee77f184194b8466544c0b/notebook/static/notebook/js/notebook.js#L2781), but that didn't seem to do anything. Any pointers to debug this scenario or how the copy code gets called?

Relevant information:

1. Jupyter is being served via `jupyterhub==0.6.1`
2. `jupyter==1.0.0`
3. `ipykernel==4.3.1`

Comment: Inserting debugging stuff in the JS is a bit trickier because the JS files are bundled into one big file to optimise loading. The [contributor docs](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contributing.html) describe how to compile the JS. Is there any info in the browser JS console or the notebook logs when this happens? Can you reproduce it with a plain notebook server run with `jupyter notebook --debug`, and if so, are there any error messages in the terminal?

Comment: @Thomas there are no messages in the js console...but i haven't tries the `debug` thing. Will try and update here

Comment: @ThomasK thanks for the hint. I was able to debug using chrome inspector. Turns out python read-only notebooks were opening up as dirty and as such a copy was triggering a save which was failing. Think I have stumbled upon `https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1112`